# Html character misalignment while padding with whitesapce

Tags: html, whitespace, padding

I'm trying to show an alignment of some protein subsequences in a simple HTML document
printing the characters in constant width Courier typeface .

However left padding with space '&nbsp' is involved and there is a misalignment of characters, particularly when there is a long stretch of padding characters.

[image]

I guess this arises because of difference in width of the whitespace and when I pad with some other character like "X", it gets perfectly aligned.

I would like to pad with spaces for better appearance of the document.
Can anybody suggest some simple HTML solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a "mono" font so that all char have the same width.

For that, you can check the "font-family" CSS property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family.

For example:

```
body {
 font-family: monospace;
}
```

Comment: I'm using Courier which is a fixed width typeface

Comment: Is it installed on the machine you are using or imported via webfont?

If you use a font by name it should be installed or imported. I tried the same with the family monospace (as in my response above) and it aligns perfectly.

By giving the famille name, it takes one of the monospace font available.

Comment: Finally managed to run it. Thanks